# Where clause with multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and I am using MS SQL Server Management Studio 2014. I have 3 tables called Pizza, Pizza_Topping and Topping. I want to list the pizzas that have TOPPING1 and TOPPING2 as toppings.
This is what I have came up with,

```
select  Pizza.pizzaID, Pizza.pizzaName, Topping.toppingName

from Pizza left join Pizza_Topping on
Pizza.pizzaID = Pizza_Topping.pizzaID

left join Topping on
Topping.toppingID = Pizza_Topping.toppingID

where Topping.toppingName in ('topping1', 'topping2')
```

and this gives me

```
pizzaID    pizzaName        toppingName
-------- ---------------- --------------
PZ002   |   PIZZA1       |    TOPPING1
PZ002   |   PIZZA1       |    TOPPING2
PZ010   |   PIZZA5       |    TOPPING1
PZ010   |   PIZZA5       |    TOPPING2
PZ011   |   PIZZA6       |    TOPPING1
PZ012   |   PIZZA7       |    TOPPING2
```

I only need first four rows because last two pizzas only have one of the toppings not both.
I have tried this as well,

```
GROUP BY Pizza.pizzaID,Pizza.pizzaName, Topping.toppingName HAVING COUNT(toppingName) >= 2
```

but it didn't give the expected result. that line can be used if I am going to display only `pizzaID` and `pizzaName` but i want to display `toppingName` as well.

to be more clear, this what I am expecting

```
pizzaID    pizzaName        toppingName
-------- ---------------- --------------
PZ002   |   PIZZA1       |    TOPPING1
PZ002   |   PIZZA1       |    TOPPING2
PZ010   |   PIZZA5       |    TOPPING1
PZ010   |   PIZZA5       |    TOPPING2
```

Please tell me how to achieve this result. Thanks

Comment: instead of `where Topping.toppingName in ('topping1', 'topping2')` try `Topping.toppingName = 'topping1' and Topping.toppingName ='topping2`

Comment: @sachu I did try that way as well, but it doesn't give any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could be done more easily if you can get the `count()` in your subquery and then join back all the pizzaid's that have count greater than 1 something like this:

```
SELECT q1.pizzaID
    ,q1.PizzaName
    ,t.ToppingName
FROM (
    SELECT Pizza.pizzaID
        ,Pizza.pizzaName
        ,count(topping.ToppingName) total_count
    FROM Pizza
    INNER JOIN Pizza_Topping ON Pizza.pizzaID = Pizza_Topping.pizzaID
    INNER JOIN Topping ON Topping.toppingID = Pizza_Topping.toppingID
    GROUP BY Pizza.pizzaID
        ,Pizza.pizzaName
    HAVING count(topping.ToppingName) > 1
    ) q1
INNER JOIN Pizza_Topping pt ON q1.pizzaID = pt.pizzaID
INNER JOIN Topping t ON t.toppingID = pt.toppingID
WHERE t.toppingName in ('topping1', 'topping2')
```

Comment: It gives me "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'. Is it possible to have a where clause in a group by function ?

Comment: Apologies...I didn't include the aggregate values in my previous queries. Hopefully this should work for you.

Comment: It still gives "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE' so I gave a try using,  group by Topping.ToppingName HAVIING count(Topping.ToppingName)>1. But no luck not the expected result.

Comment: I cleaned up the query for you a little bit, this one should work!

Comment: I have executed your code but the result is not as expected. I have inserted what I got after executing your code as an edit to my question, for further references.

Comment: Just forgot to add `where` clause to it. Should give you expected result now.

Comment: Wonderful! Glad that it's returning expected output.:)

Answer (score 1):

You are almost correct.  You need to remove `ToppingName` from the `GROUP BY`:

```
GROUP BY Pizza.pizzaID, Pizza.pizzaName
HAVING COUNT(toppingName) >= 2
```

You also need to remove it from the `SELECT` if it is also there:

```
select p.pizzaID, p.pizzaName
from Pizza p join
     Pizza_Topping pt
     on p.pizzaID = pt.pizzaID join
     Topping t
     ont.toppingID = pt.toppingID
where t.toppingName in ('topping1', 'topping2')
group by p.pizzaID, p.pizzaName
having count(*) >= 2;
```

Also notice two things.  Because you have a condition on toppings, the `left join` is unnecessary.  You are only looking for matches, so `inner join` is appropriate.  The use of table aliases makes the query easier to write and to read.

This assumes that pizzas cannot have duplicate toppings.  If so, then change the last condition to:

```
having count(distinct t.toppingName) >= 2
```

Comment: I want to display ToppingName as well.

Comment: it’s perfectly gives me the pizzaID and pizzaName of the pizzas that have topping 1 and topping 2. But i want to display the topping name in the result table. Is it possible? Or am I struggling to achieve something impossible?

Answer (score 0):

You have to join to the pizza_topping and topping tables twice.

```
select yourfields
from pizza join pizza_topping pt1 on pizza.pizzaID = pt1.pizzaID
join topping t1 on pt1.toppingID = t1.toppingId

join pizza_topping pt2 on pizza.pizzaID = pt2.pizzaID
join topping t2 on pt2.toppingID = t2.toppingId

where t1.toppingName = 'topping1'
and t2.toppingName = 'topping2'
```

Comment: I think "topping t1" and "pt.toppingID" in 5th line should be topping t2 and pt2.toppingID  right ?

Comment: oops.  how emabarrassing.

Answer (score 0):

Get your result without topping name . Wrap it in a view and do an inner join with Topping table .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My professor hasn't cover creating Views yet so I don't know how to create or handle views. I would really appreciate if you can show me how to create a view.

Comment: Nepali Rookie just did it now. All in the sub select is called a view.

Answer (score 0):

To include the toppings you can do the COUNT-logic using Windowed Aggregate Functions:

```
SELECT p.pizzaID, p.pizzaName, dt.toppingName
FROM Pizza AS p 
JOIN
 (
   SELECT p.pizzaID, t.toppingName,
      COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY p.pizzaID) AS cnt -- number of matching toppings
   FROM Pizza_Topping AS pt
   JOIN Topping AS t
     ON t.toppingID = pt.toppingID
   WHERE t.toppingName IN ('topping1', 'topping2')
 ) AS dt
  ON p.pizzaID = dt.pizzaID 
WHERE cnt = 2 -- number of searched toppings
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by using group by statement restricted to Pizza Id. Please refer below query.

```
   select  Pizza.pizzaID, Pizza.pizzaName, Pizza_Toppings.Remark
   from Pizza  join Pizza_Toppings on
   Pizza.pizzaID = Pizza_Toppings.pizzaID
   join Toppings on
   Toppings.toppingID = Pizza_Toppings.toppingID
   where Pizza.PizzaId in (
   select Pizza.PizzaID
   from Pizza  join Pizza_Toppings on
   Pizza.pizzaID = Pizza_Toppings.pizzaID
   join Toppings on
   Toppings.toppingID = Pizza_Toppings.toppingID
   where Toppings.TopingName in ('topping1', 'topping2')
   group by pizza.PizzaId 
   having count(Pizza.PizzaId ) > 1)
```

Please let me know if this does not work for you.